# Questions about conventional commit messages in git

Tags: git, conventional-commits

I'm trying to adapt to **conventional commit messages**, described in this [article](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/git-commit-msg.html).

Here's a snippet from the article:

Allowed `<type>` values:

```
feat (new feature)
fix (bug fix)
docs (changes to documentation)
style (formatting, missing semi colons, etc; no code change)
refactor (refactoring production code)
test (adding missing tests, refactoring tests; no production code change)
chore (updating grunt tasks etc; no production code change)
```

But sometimes there are changes w/c are hard to categorize into this types. I'll list some of changes w/c i find confusing on what type to use

What types should i use in this cases

1. I added a css style on an existing component(react, angular, vue, etc)
2. I edited configuration files in my project such as `package.json`, `.prettierc`, etc.
3. Renaming a file
4. Deleting a file

Comment: Well, why did you add the CSS style?  Did you do it to create a new feature, or to fix a bug, or...?

Comment: @NateEldredge - so that means it's a "feat" type since i only add styles and not fix some design. Ok, i get it now. It depends on the the reason you add the css.

But what about renaming files, i guess it's a "refactor" type. With the config files, i think they are "chore" types. But what about deleting files? Let's say those files are no longer needed, does that means it's just a "refactor"?

Answer (score 10):

Here's the more detailed [conventional commit types](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#type)

> - **build**: Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm)
> - **ci**: Changes to our CI configuration files and scripts (examples: CircleCi, SauceLabs)
> - **docs**: Documentation only changes
> - **feat**: A new feature
> - **fix**: A bug fix
> - **perf**: A code change that improves performance
> - **refactor**: A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature
> - **test**: Adding missing tests or correcting existing tests

For each of your questions, I've put the type I'd use under it.

> I added a css style on an existing component(react, angular, vue, etc)
>
> `feat`

> I edited configuration files in my project such as package.json, .prettierc, etc.
>
> `build`

> Renaming a file
>
> `refactor`, potentially add [`BREAKING CHANGE`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#commit-message-footer)

> Deleting a file
>
> `refactor`, potentially add [`BREAKING CHANGE`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#commit-message-footer)

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is inspired from Angular's commit rules:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#commits

Also see:

https://github.com/commitizen/conventional-commit-types/blob/master/index.json

https://github.com/pvdlg/conventional-commit-types

I think for a few of your points, like 'deleting a file', it probably depends **why** you're deleting it. For example, removing a file because you've moved its in code into a more logical location - its probably a **refactor**.